# A drum is rolling down a hill - is the force of friction with the surface a constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotation

A drum is rolling down a hill without slipping. We ignore air drag.

In order for the drum to not slip, there must be a (static, correct?) friction force exerted by the surface on the drum at the point of contact.

This friction force acts in the direction opposite to the velocity of the center of mass of the drum.

In an exercise I'm working on, when calculating the translational work done on the object, I had to do a line integral on the total force acting on the object. So at one point this meant the integral included $f$ - the friction force.

In the solution, it seems that the authors assume that $f$ is constant.

Is the friction force indeed constant? Why or why not?

Comment: Is air drag to be considered or not?

Comment: Why is static friction contributing to translational energy?

Comment: @MichaelK Air drag is ignored.

Comment: @JonCuster Do you mean that it doesn't do work, because the point where the static friction is applied does not move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **friction must be static** because the point that is in contact with the ground at a particular instant is in rest (wrt ground).

Yes, the **frictional force is constant**.

mgsin(θ) - ƒ = ma

ƒR = {m(r^2)/2}* (α)

---

m = mass of drum
r = radius of drum
θ = angle of hill
α = angular acceleration of drum wrt center of mass
a = linear acceleration if drum
ƒ = frictional force

By solving we get α constant, and therefore value of ƒ is also constant

PS -: In pure rolling, friction does not contribute to work because the point of contact between the drum and the ground is instantaneously at rest wrt ground frame.

Comment: The static friction  is constant, but it does not does not contribute to work, since it is orthogonal  to the movement. so the f must be something different.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).